# Cannot kill httpd process even with -9

Tags: centos, ssl, httpd, kill-process

I cannot kill httpd process on my VPS running centos 6.5.

I tried killing it with -9 flag which didn't work either.

Output of command: ps aux | grep httpd

```
root     29459  0.0  0.0 103252   828 pts/0    S+   11:24   0:00 grep httpd
```

What is strange is that every time when kill -9 29459 command is entered the pid of the above process increments by 2 and kill command returns **No such process**

What happened before this was that I tried to restart httpd but because of an error with SSL it couldn't restart

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't kill a process that is not running!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to kill the grep command, which you have just run. Since the grep command already completed, you cannot kill it.

Comment: So how do I get correct PID of httpd process?

Comment: 1) fix the reported error 2) start httpd 3) ps auxww | grep httpd

Comment: Either the process isn't running or it has a different name. Possibly `pidof apache2` could work.

Comment: Why not just use the native `service httpd stop` command?